# Dynamic input selection with RShiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following code:

```
library(shiny)

vec <- seq(1,10)
ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel(""),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fluidRow(
      selectInput("city", "Select number", vec, multiple = TRUE),
      actionButton("First_fives", "First Fives" ),
      actionButton("Last_fives", "Last Fives"),
      actionButton("ok", "OK"))
    ),

    mainPanel(
      fluidRow(
        h5("Selected numbers:"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {


}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I would like to be able to:

- when I click on "First fives", empty the select input box and add the numbers 1 to 5 to my select input box
- when I click on "Last fives", empty the select input box and add the numbers 6 to 10 to my select input box
- when I click on "OK", I would like the selected items to appear under "selected numbers:"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mainPanel(
  fluidRow(
    h5("Selected numbers:")),
    textOutput('num')         #Add 'num' output to your UI 

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {    #Add session variable, which is necessary to updateSelectInput
          observeEvent(input$First_fives,{
          updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "city", choices = vec[1:5])
 })

          observeEvent(input$Last_fives,{
          updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "city", choices = vec[6:10])
 })

          data <- reactiveValues()
          observeEvent(input$ok,{
                       data$selected <- input$city
 })

          output$num <- renderText({data$selected})
}
```